# Geowebcache bounding box to tile conversion is not working properly (EPSG:4326)

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache, tilecache

I am trying to make Geoserver and built in Geowebcache work together.
I have a page with google maps and I am rendering images from a published WMS layer using getTileUrl function.

Unfortunately I am getting wrong tiles when geowebcache is activated.

Here is a request which uses caching (caching is enabled for png8):

```
    http://myserver/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/png8&LAYERS=layername&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=28.7841796875,40.94671366508002,28.828125,40.979898069620155
```

response headers:

```
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Content-Disposition:inline; filename=layername.png8
    Content-Type:image/png
    Date:Fri, 30 May 2014 08:19:17 GMT
    ETag:91591a0d685881053a9d4761f42086f8
    geowebcache-cache-result:HIT
    geowebcache-crs:EPSG:4326
    geowebcache-gridset:EPSG:4326
    geowebcache-layer:layername
    geowebcache-tile-bounds:28.7841796875,40.95703125,28.828125,41.0009765625
    geowebcache-tile-index:[4751, 2980, 12]
    Last-Modified:Thu, 29 May 2014 16:31:31 GMT
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Here is a second request which hits directly to geoserver (caching is enabled for jpeg):

```
    http://myserver/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYERS=layername&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=28.7841796875,40.94671366508002,28.828125,40.979898069620155
```

response headers:

```
    Content-Disposition:inline; filename=layername.jpg
    Content-Type:image/jpeg
    Date:Fri, 30 May 2014 08:19:01 GMT
    geowebcache-cache-result:MISS
    geowebcache-miss-reason:no tile cache for requested format
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Although I am requesting for the same bounding box, the first request which uses geowebcache returns wrong portion of the map while the second works fine.

Also, the first request finds a tile in the 12th zoom level while my map is actually in zoom level 13.

I guess, bbox -> tms tile mapping conversion is not working properly.
Anyone can propose suggestions on how I am doing wrong?

Note: my wms layer has native & declared srs:4326

Note 2: I am not using openlayers.

Edit:  I can check I am using the correct bounding box using the following url:

```
   http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/
   Google: (4751,3072)
   TMS: (4751,5119)
   Zoom:13

   == Tile Boundaries ==
   WGS84 datum (longitude/latitude):
   28.7841796875 40.94671366508002
   28.828125 40.979898069620155
```

But webgeocache finds [4751, 2980, 12].
In fact when I look at webgeocache directory tile x=4751 exists only in level 12 but not in level 13.

Edit 2: Example for topp:states layer 
        Google: (301,382)
        TMS: (301,641)
        Zoom:10

```
    http://localhost:9090/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/png8&LAYERS=topp:states&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=-73.828125,41.50857729743935,-73.125,42.032974332441405

    response headers:
    Cache-Control:max-age=3600, must-revalidate
    Content-Disposition:inline; filename=geoserver-dispatch.image
    Content-Type:image/png
    Expires:Fri, 30 May 2014 10:47:17 GMT
    geowebcache-cache-result:HIT
    geowebcache-crs:EPSG:4326
    geowebcache-gridset:EPSG:4326
    geowebcache-tile-bounds:-73.828125,41.484375,-73.125,42.1875
    geowebcache-tile-index:[151, 187, 8]
    geowebcache-tile-index:[151, 187, 8]
    Last-Modified:Fri, 30 May 2014 09:43:38 GMT
    Server:Jetty(6.1.8)
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked

    Correct tile should be:
    http://localhost:9090/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYERS=topp:states&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=-73.828125,41.50857729743935,-73.125,42.032974332441405
```

Comment: Can you repeat the behavior with the topp:states demo layer and paste corresponding URLs for us? It would be so much easier to start looking at the issue if we all can use same data.

Comment: I have edited the question with an example from topp:states layer

Comment: I do not believe you can compare the predefined gridset EPSG:4326 with Google tiles. Try with the GWC gridset EPSG:900913 if you want to do tile-by-tile comparisons.

Anyhow, I can see what you mean on my computer and local Geoserver+GWC. Thanks for the new links.

Comment: My original data is in 4326. I am caching to some extend but if the user zooms too much the server will bring the tiles from geoserver (not from cache). If I request using EPSG:900913 then the server will need to handle 4326->900913 convertion in those zoom levels which I think would hurt the performance. I can change the original data to 900913, but my application uses 4326, if I use wfs for example to bring some features than I will need to convert again which again hurts performance.

Comment: That's not a problem, I just meant that because the gridsets are different you can not blindly believe that Google zoom level 13 in EPSG:3857 is also zoom level 13 in EPSG:4326 grid of GWC. But there is some real problem with BBOXes. Which Geoserver version you have?

Comment: I have version 2.4.3. Also I found this: http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/concepts/tiles.html
It says there are different number of tiles in each layer for 900913 and 4326.

Comment: Stay tuned, I will try to find our what happens. WMS requests to geoserver/wms and gwc/service/wms must return similar map or it is a but. Meanwhile, it would be nice if you could downgrade to some Geoserver 2.3 version and check if the error is also there.

Comment: Probably you are right that these gridsets are not interchangeble: http://localhost:9090/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.gwc.web.gridset.GridSetEditPage&gridSet=EPSG:900913 vs http://localhost:9090/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.gwc.web.gridset.GridSetEditPage&gridSet=EPSG:4326. About your comment : WebGeoCache probably tries to find the most appropriate tile with given bounding box and if the error is above 10%, it does not return a tile